# Advantages of using different domain for customers in a multi tenant environment

Tags: cookies, dns, subdomain, multi-tenant, saas

If I want a multi-tenant environment where customers can create subdomains, what are the pros and cons of creating those subdomains under myexample.com if my main company domain is example.com?

I noticed that Shopify uses `myshopify.com` under which their create subdomains for their customers.

Answer (score 3):

Coupled with [the fact that this is better for security,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823690/32495), it certainly appears that there's a pattern and good reason why companies do this.

Here are some examples:

- Shopify

  - Uses [shopify.com](http://shopify.com) for marketing and [myshopify.com](http://myshopify.com) for subdomain.
- Basecamp

  - Uses [basecamphq.com](http://basecamphq.com) for marketing and [basecamp.com](http://basecamp.com) for subdomains.
- Intercom Articles

  - Uses [intercom.com](http://intercom.com) for marketing and [intercom.help](http://intercom.help) for subdomains.
- Harvest

  - Uses [getharvest.com](http://getharvest.com) for marketing and [harvestapp.com](http://harvestapp.com) for subdomains.
- Status.io

  - Uses [statuspage.io](http://statuspage.io) for marketing and [statuspagestaging.com](http://statuspagestaging.com) for subdomains.

Also [this article points out the issue with untrusted content](https://www.mxsasha.eu/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/) (as is the case with Shopify:

> Although cookie domains do help to limit the scope of your cookies, it
>   is still best to avoid having untrusted hosts under your domain. This
>   is why GitHub pages are hosted under github.io, not github.com, for
>   example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the web domain name prefixed by 'my' is purly emotional rather than technical.  It's in the back-end that the domains need to be different, as a resource for enforcing security.  There needs to be at least a production and an internal domain.  A full suite might be Dev, DevQA, UAT, production and internal domains, with a limited number of people being able to transfer code and/or data across domains.